# Another way to create html table

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, html-table

I got this Javascript map structure:

key (String)       -      value (Array())

```
   String "customerId"    =   Array{"123123", "298191", "93202"}
   String "customerName"  =   Array{"fran", "nick", "jan"}
   String "pobox"         =   Array{"18239", "129319", "123123"}
```

So basically, the value is an array with all the customerIds, all the customerNames, and so on.
The table I want to create would be generated in Javascript like:

```
customerId   customerName    pobox
123123         fran           18239
298191         nick           129319
93202          jan            123123
```

Is it possible to make it in Javascript? Tried but its so complicated :/

I've been doing this:

```
function createBodyRowsByMapObject(map, tbody) {

    for(a in map) {
        var arr = map[a];
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for(k in arr) {
                    //here i would be getting the array value.
            createTableData(row, arr[k]);
        }
    }
    tbody.appendChild(row);
}
```

Comment: It would be much better if you posted the javascript code you created to try to solve this problem than just blindly ask for some one else to implement your work for you.

Comment: What's your *actual* data structure? What you posted is invalid.

Comment: It's not _that_ complicated, but you're right, it's a lot of code for such a trivial task. I think there might libraries that can take some of the work out of your hands if you know where to look; probably jQuery will help a lot.

Comment: It's a huge code, i already have a code to create an HTML table in javascript, but in a normal way, adding row by row element, and not all the column elements at once :S going to edit to put some of my code

Comment: invalid data structure? is a String - Array map in javascript :(

Comment: Yes, but it's not an actual js object. I suppose it actually looks like `var map = {"customerId" : ["123123", "298191", "93202"] ... }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume your data structure is as follows:

```
var obj = {
    "customerId":["123123","298191","93202"],
    "customerName":["fran","nick","jan"],
    "pobox":["18239","129319","123123"]
};
```

It's easier than you might think to convert that to a table:

```
var table = document.createElement('table'), rows = [], k, l, i;
for( k in obj) {
    l = obj[k].length;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( !rows[i]) rows[i] = table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
        rows[i].appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
               .appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj[k][i];
    }
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: wtf :o hahaha it worked!!!!! you are a genius!! thanks man! can't believe it worked :O anyway i wasn't capable of doing that, tho. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can always try using a templating solution such as [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) -- this makes spitting out markup as simple as it can be.